# Reporting services Expression doesn't work

Tags: sql-server, reporting-services

I am trying to check the field(date field) value if it is null or empty. If it is empty or null then do not display anything. If there is a value then display the value of another field. But the following expression doesn't seem to be working. Could you please let me know if there are any suggestions?

```
=IIF(Trim(Fields!field_date.Value) = "", "", Fields!field_name.Value)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
=IIF(String.IsNullOrEmpty(Fields!field_date.Value), "", Fields!field_name.Value)
```

Answer (score 1):

This will check if the field_date value is empty:

```
=IIF(IsNothing(Trim(Fields!field_date.Value)), "", Fields!field_name.Value)
```

Comment: You should put the IsNothing inside of the Trim() function or remove Trim() entirely, but the idea is sound.

Comment: @gbn : Empty strings don't matter: if handed an empty string, this will return an empty string either way.